# regex for price validation

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regular expression which accepts maximum 5 digits before decimal and maximum 2 digits after decimal. Decimal part is optional and should not accept if 0 is the only digit. But accepts if 0 is followed by other digits after or before decimal.
For example:

Valid data are : 12345.12,123.12,0.12,00.12,1.2,0123.12

Invalid data are: 0,00,000,0000,00000

I have made an expression `^\d{0,5}(\.\d{1,2})?$"` but this does not work if the digit starts with 0.

Comment: Do you allow empty strings and values like `00001.01`?

Comment: empty string is not allowed but values like 00001.01 is valid

Answer (score 4):

```
^(?!0+$)\d{0,5}(.\d{1,2})?$

 ^^^^^^^
```

Just add a `lookahead` which would fail the regex if it finds only `0`.

EDIT:

If you dont want to allow `0.0` use

```
^(?!0+(\.0+)?$)\d{0,5}(.\d{1,2})?$
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

```
^\d{0,5}(?!(\.|,)0{2})(\.|,)\d{1,2}$
```

`(?!(\.|,)0{2})` asserts the number doesn't contain only `0`s after decimal point.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dE2pL3/4)

Answer (score 0):

> empty string is not allowed but values like 00001.01 is valid

You can use the following regex with negative look-aheads that check for disallowed values:

```
 ^(?!$)(?!0+$)\d{0,5}(?:\.(?!0{1,2}$)\d{1,2})?$
  ^^^^^ ^^^^^              ^^^^^^^^^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iA5eU6/5)

The regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!$)` - make sure the string is not empty (the end of string does not appear right after the beginning)
- `(?!0+$)` - makes sure the integer number does not consist of only zeros
- `\d{0,5}` - 0 to 5 digits
- `(?:\.(?!0{1,2}$)\d{1,2})?` - an optional sequence of...

  - `\.` - a decimal period
  - `(?!0{1,2}$)\d{1,2}` - 2 or 1 digits (`\d{1,2}`) that is not `0` or `00` (`(?!0{1,2}$)`)
- `$` - end of string

Comment: I have updated my answer, and it seems only my regex does not allow empty strings and only `0000`, `0000.0` or `0000.00`.